# Common Lisp: avoid evaluation of a symbol in a function

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a trivial problem in Common Lisp. I need to write a function that takes a symbol as a parameter (i.e. a name of a function or a name of a variable), then do other things, and then print that symbol without evaluating it. Quote doesn't work in this case, so how can I do this? For example, suppose that I defined `var` as the integer `3` with `defparameter`, then the function should have this behavior:

```
(my-function var)
REPL: var is a symbol and its value is 3.
```

How can I print `var`? How can I exactly see `var` on the REPL, or any other name I gave to the input variable in `my-function`? Can someone  help me?

Comment: please format code as such by indenting with 4 spaces

Comment: What do you mean with "quote doesn't work in this case"?

Comment: @jkiiski I mean that I tried to quote var, but of course doesn't work for my aim, because the problem was I write a function while I should write a macro as Basile suggests me

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"? There's no reason why a function couldn't produce the output in your example with a quoted symbol as an argument (for example, `(defun my-function (arg) (format t "~a = ~a~%" arg (symbol-value arg)))`).

Comment: @jkiiski you're right, it works also in this way. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The features you are seeking is not possible to do with functions since they might have been compiled such that parameters are just passed on a stack and the code looks at memory indexes and not variables.

You are looking for some sort of meta programming and that is what macros are for:

```
(defmacro info (expr)
  (let ((compile-type (type-of expr)) (tmp (gensym "tmp")))
    `(let ((,tmp ,expr))
       (format t "REPL: ~s is a ~a and it's value is ~s~%" ',expr ',compile-type ,tmp)
       ,tmp)))


(info "test")
; REPL: "test" is a (simple-base-string 4) and it's value is "test"
; ==>  "test"
(info *print-circle*)
; REPL: *print-circle* is a symbol and it's value is nil
; ==> nil
(info #'+)
; REPL: #'+ is a cons and it's value is #<system-function +>
; ==> #<system-function +>
(info (+ 3 4))
; REPL: (+ 3 4) is a cons and it's value is 7
; ==> 7
```

Comment: Thanks! It's exactly what I'm trying to do!

Answer (score 3):

> *Quote doesn't work in this case, so how can I do?*

How so? Quote does work in this case. When we invoke:

```
(my-function 'var)
```

The `my-function` function is now taking the symbol `var` as an argument; `var` is not evaluated.

If `var` is a dynamic variable, its value can be inspected or latered by that function, using the accessor `symbol-value`:

```
(defun my-function (sym)
  (format t "value of dynamic variable ~s is ~s~%."
          sym
          (symbol-value sym)))
```

If instead we want to treat `sym` as a function, that is even simpler:

```
(defun my-function (sym)
  (funcall sym 42))  ;; call function, pass 42 as argument
```

In Common Lisp, a symbol can be specified where a function object is expected. The symbol is resolved to a function in the global environment, and that function is used. This is why `(mapcar 'fun ...)` can be used instead of `(mapcar #'fun ...)`. (These normally have the same effect, but there is a subtle difference in the compilation semantics which shows up when functions are dynamically redefined.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't have `my-function` be an ordinary (`defun`-ed) function, because they always evaluate their arguments. You may want to make it a macro.

Read a good Common Lisp book.